# Error with JS roles TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

I am having a little bit of an issue with setting roles within the admin panel of my site. the roles i have set are mmUser, mmMerchant, mmAdmin

when a user signs up they are auto set to mmUser, within the admin panel i am trying to set them to mmMerchant, right now i can do it manually throiugh the MongoDB set up. the weird thing is that i can downgrade them from merchant to mmUser through the panel but not put them as merchant.

any ideas?

```
Controller.get('/make-merchant/:id/', function(req, res, next){
    let id = req.params.id;

    Collections
    .Schemas
    .Users
    .find()
    .then(results => {
        results.roles.push('mmMerchant');
        results.save()
        .then(user=>{
            res.redirect('/management/users/');
        })
        .catch(next)
    })
    .catch(next)
});
```

The Error log states this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Collections.Schemas.Users.find.then.results (D:\pre200\pre\routes\management\users.js:69:22)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

UP TO DATE CODE

```
Controller.get('/make-merchant/:id/', function(req, res, next){
    let id = req.params.id;

    Collections
    .Schemas
    .Users
    .find({_id: id })
    .then(results => {
       results[0].roles.push('mmMerchant');
        results.save()
        .then(user=>{
            res.redirect('/management/users/');
        })
        .catch(next)
    })
    .catch(next)
});
```

Comment: `results.roles.push('mmMerchant');` fails. `results.roles` is undefined. What does a `console.log(results)` give you?

Comment: @Kristianmitk the console is stating this `Caught exception:  Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader `

Comment: where did you added the `console.log(..)` ? Put it right after the first `.then()`

Comment: @Kristianmitk okay my mistake i put it at the end  after the second catch,  its now coming up with [ model ] with every function in the Web app. it seems its not adding into the array for the roles. roles
:
Array[2]
0
:
"mmUser"
1
:
""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated,

i know have fixed this error, for anyone else thats suffering from the same error.

here is my code.

```
Controller.get('/make-merchant/:id/', function(req, res, next){
    let id = req.params.id;

    Collections
    .Schemas
    .Users
    .findOne({_id: id})
    .then(results => {
             let merchantIndex = results.roles.indexOf('mmUser');

        if(merchantIndex > -1){
            results.roles.push('mmMerchant');
        }

        results.save()
        .then(user=>{
            res.redirect('/management/users/');

        })
        .catch(next)
    })
    .catch(next)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Model.find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find) will return an array of documents, so it would be `results[0].roles`.

You would use [`Model.findOne`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findone_findOne) or here [`Model.findById`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyid_findById) this will only return one document (or `null`).

If possible you could also update the document directly with something like [`Model.findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate)

For example you could use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator:

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { 
  $push: { roles: 'mmMerchant' } 
})
```

An alternative would be [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) this would prevent duplication.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the awnser, where abouts would i change to fit Model.FindByIdAndUpdate?

Comment: Added an example, there are also other operations to manipulate arrays in mongodb.

Comment: see for some reason now im getting the error `TypeError: results.save is not a function` i must have missed something somewhere. See Edited Question for up to date code.

Comment: I guess that's a mongoose problem, I'm not using mongoose to often to be honest. I will take a look if I find the time.

Comment: Hey mate, did you get a chance to have a look?